# Using an animated gif in Qualtrics

Tags: gif, survey, animated, qualtrics

Does anyone have tips of how to use moving gifs in Qualtrics? I want to add a (fake) "page loading" animated gif. I have added the gif I want to use to the Graphics Library, but when I display it the animation doesn't work.

Just FYI, I am using Google Chrome as a browser for the survey.

I did look through this thread: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2004/Dec/27/Animated-GIF-images-in-hidden-page-elements but still couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out how to solve the problem. Apparently Qualtrics generates some php stuff to display graphics from its library. If I just upload the image I want to display to an external website, I can use Qualtrics to link to the url. If I do that, the animation works just fine.

Just thought I'd share in case someone else runs into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To use a loading screen in Qualtrics, insert a graphic and select "Use a graphic from the web". Just find a page you like through a google search and insert the url into Qualtrics.